# How to remove windows hello fingerprint data, for user that no longer exists on the computer?

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, fingerprint

When I quit work for last employer, I took the laptop with me (Lenovo T420).
When I disabled the domain, the username I was using before disappeared (tied to domain).

I already had local admin user created, and all the data backed up so that was not a problem.

But the problem is that previous domain user had a Windows Hello fingerprint associated with it. And although I went to the bios and deleted all fingerprint data, and also installed Lenovo ThinkVantage Fingerprint software and deleted all fingerprints in it as well, Windows 10 still does not let me associate index finger with my new local account, saying:

> That fingerprint has already been set up on another account. Try a different finger.

I removed the complete `c:\users\olddomainuser` folder, and used the Control Panel to remove olddomainuser - but error still persists.

Where does Windows 10 store the Windows Hello/biometric data - can i reset/delete it, and start fresh without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: You are going to have to reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar problem which still persists after resetting TPM and reinstalling the OS completely...

However, some people have reported success after deleting the file *inside*

> `C:\\Windows\System32\WinBioDatabase\`

and rebooting. So you might give that a try. Note that you will have to disable the Windows Biometric Service to delete the file.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Powershell(Administrator)

```
stop-service WbioSrvc
Delete all files under:C:\Windows\System32\WinBioDatabase\
start-service WbioSrvc
```

why stop the service, there could be a file lock and than you cant remove all files.

Answer (score 0):

after reinstall e.t.c i finaly figured the issue.

in bios select reset finger print on reboot (you have to set a bios password to enable this option) after this the problem is fixed, this issue is not the OS but the bios storing old finger prints

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [this file](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n1mgf11w.exe) and ran the install with two modifications:

1. I "installed" the driver to `c:\DRIVERS\WIN\FPRtempfolder`
2. The installer unzipped the files than stopped at one final dialog. I UNCHECKED the box that said "Install Synaptics Metallica MOC Touch Fingerprint Reader Driver," then clicked Finish.
3. I navigated to the `FPRtempfolder` and copied `SynapticsUtility.exe` dated 4/4/2018 to my own folder, and ran it from there. The utility let me delete all of the registered fingerprints.

Source : https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/That-fingerprint-has-already-been-set-up-on-another-account-Yoga/m-p/4230475#M68371